# State not mutating with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Why does it constantly log 0 every second after runTimer is executed?

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0)
 const runTimer = (x) => {
   let interval = setInterval(() => {
     setTimer(prev => prev - 1)
     console.log(timer)
   }, 1000)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

## The value is scoped and will always be the same

Try logging the value outside since the state change will force a render.
Also State should never "mutate". State should always be a new object not a mutation.

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0)
 const runTimer = (x) => {
   let interval = setInterval(() => {
     setTimer(prev => prev - 1)
   }, 1000)
 }
 console.log(timer)
```

### Your second question

The scope of `let interval` means you can only `clearInterval` at that level. I'm not sure of a good way to do that from this method. You probably want to use the hook `useEffect` to set the interval.

Comment: Any way I can access timer state prop within that function? I'd like to kill the interval on timer === 0

Answer (score 0):

`setTimer` is an async call, you won't be able to get the `timer` immediate after setting the state.

[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is here for rescue.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your action
}, [timer]);
```

You will always get the updated `timer` value.